# Adding a column to a data frame whose name is not known at compile time

Tags: r

How can I add a column to a data frame whose name is not known at design time? I tried *assign*, but it doesn't work. For example:

```
for(i in 1:50){
  columnName<-paste0("train$field.",as.character(i))
  assign(nombreVariable,fieldsList[[i]])
}
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. We have no way of knowing what "nombreVariable" and "fieldsList" are.

Comment: `x <- "X"; BOD[x] <- 1:nrow(BOD)`  adds a column whose name is held in variable `x` to the builtin data frame `BOD`.

Comment: @user3640617, they were variable names

Answer (score 0):

you can use (inside a loop):

```
...
colname <- "your_colname"
df[[colname]] <- "desired_values"
...
```

this is possible because `df$name` and `df[["name"]]` both select a column (as a vector)